# Error while trying to cross-compile libnl for android arm64

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I have previously used my standalone aarch64-linux-android toolchain to crosscompile projects for my android phone.

While trying to crosscompile libnl (3.2.25, and older versions as well), I keep getting this error while making -

```
CCLD     nf-ct-list
../src/lib/.libs/libnl-cli-3.so: undefined reference to `getsubopt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My setup environment -

```
#!/bin/bash
# Add the standalone toolchain to the search path.
export PATH=$PATH:/home/john/toolchain-gcc/bin

# Tell configure what tools to use.
target_host=aarch64-linux-android
export AR=$target_host-ar
#export AS=$target_host-gcc
export CC=$target_host-gcc
export CXX=$target_host-g++
export LD=$target_host-ld
export STRIP=$target_host-strip

# Tell configure what flags Android requires.
export CFLAGS="-fPIE -fPIC"
export LDFLAGS="-pie"
```

As far as I googled, I figured getsubopt is part of the standard library. Isn't it already included in my toolchain? It's weird I already compiled projects using my toolchain, but libnl fails.

Any ideas how to solve this? :(

Comment: Which `APP_PLATFORM` are you building for? A quick search through NDK r16b finds `getsubopt` in libc.so for `android-26` and `android-27`, but not for earlier platforms.

Comment: android-24 :( any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Pull the implementation from the AOSP repo maybe. But it could be that it has dependencies to other changes, etc.

Comment: Well, I made a new toolchain for android-26, didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: `export CFLAGS="-fPIE -fPIC"` looks incomplete for Android. It is missing too many options and flags, like `ANDROID` and `--sysroot`. Here's what typical Android flags looks like: [Android | GCC CXXFLAGS](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_(Command_Line)#Clang_CXXFLAGS) and [Android | Clang CXXFLAGS](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_(Command_Line)#Clang_CXXFLAGS)

Comment: @jww: It's not missing any of those options. OP is using a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain), which handles those on behalf of the user. `-fPIE -fPIC` can't be used together though I don't think. For a library you want `-fPIC` (PIE is for exectuables). Ditto on `-pie` in the `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: @JohnKalispera: Is it a different issue with android-26? The symbol should be there. If you're using an old NDK it won't be (O APIs were added in NDK r15). Might also try using Clang. GCC isn't supported and didn't work out of the box with standalone toolchains (see the KI in the changelogs).